# Chrome 27 not loading background images anymore

Tags: image, google-chrome, stylesheet, loading

This is a really weird problem that appeared in the recent version of Chrome.

I have a huge app that loads hundreds of stylesheets (in dev mode). When the page loads, obviously all styles are applied but background images are missing!
If I just do nothing and wait, suddenly the images start loading randomly...
Using dev tools I checked the network tab to see if the images are requested.. but no, just a few of them appear in contrast to the previous version of Chrome.

Does anyone know if any kind of optimization has been added in Chrome that makes images load lazily? Obviously that implementation is buggy and does not consider a page with a lot of stylesheets!

This problem does not affect the app in production, where all the stylesheets are packed and reduced to just ~10.

Tested on Linux and Windows 7

Comment: I'm having the same issue, glad there is a bug report in already. Thanks for making me think that I'm not going crazy because I checked my config files like 20 times trying to figure out where I screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with our web site on Chrome 27.0.1453.93 and 27.0.1453.94. It turns out that Chrome seemed to think that all of our .gif images were corrupt.  They wouldn't render in Chrome but they would render fine in IE, Firefox, and older Chrome versions.

I'm not sure what the underlying issue was, but I opened the images in Photoshop and re-saved them and now it works fine.

Comment: It looks like this [has been identified as a Chrome issue and will be fixed](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=242957).

Comment: I reported this issue, but I'm not just talking about gif's. Actually the problem is with png's

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=243408